# What do tripwires detect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can tripwires detect anything other than the player?

In particular, which of the following, if any, causes a tripwire to trip?

- Mobs
- Blocks (moved with pistons)
- Dropped items
- Empty minecarts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This answer has been updated according to snapshot 12w23b.*

Tripwire is active when any entity touches one of the string blocks (but not the hooks). It remains on for 5 more ticks after all the entities leave the string. *Entity* here includes players, mobs, minecarts, boats, dropped items, arrows, experience orbs, but not particle effects.

Tripwire also gets activated for 5 ticks when any of the string blocks are destroyed (unless Shears are used). When a block occupies the place of one of the string blocks (this can be a liquid or a block pushed with pistons), it is destroyed (leaving a dropped String item; this is similar to Redstone), thus activating the tripwire.

Comment: Does destroying the trip wire end-points set it off?

Comment: @fredley I was thinking whether I should stress that or not, but decided that saying "the string" everywhere is enough. No, it does not.

Comment: Fixed. You can edit your own posts you know :-)

Answer (score 1):

On [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tripwire) page it is written that tripwire detects when the player walks on it or if he destroys it without holding shears. Also it seems that tripwire can detect the player while he is riding a mine cart.

**This is only speculation:**
There isn't much more information, but I would guess that pushing a block onto a wire will destroy it. Also I would say that it can only detect entities, so no items.

Comment: Why is it speculation? Just test to see if it's true!